# Extract features HOG Descriptor

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv

I'm trying to detect players in soccer game with javacv using HOG Descriptor. I already implemented the method with the default people detector, but, the results are not satisfying. So, I extracted positive and negative images and I want to extract features using this images. 
Do anyone have any ideas on how to do this please? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You are actually implementing the idea published in this [paper](http://lear.inrialpes.fr/people/triggs/pubs/Dalal-cvpr05.pdf).

An (extended) sample code can be found at [UCI](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~dramanan/software/pose/pose-release1.2-full.tgz)

To summarize:

1. You have to generate a positive and a negative training set. This means in the positive training images you have to know where the players are located.
2. Then you have to extract the HoG features at the players position. Note the original HoG method takes input patches of size 128x64, so ensure that your players are all scaled to the same size. And important: HoG feature size depends on the extraction window size, so keep it fixed!
   Store the information in a data structure with corresponding label 1.
3. Then extract negative features from negative images and store them with corresponding label 0 or -1.
4. Use some training method. I currently work with a linear support vector machine similar to liblinear: [SVM](http://arxiv.org/abs/1312.1743)
5. Then use the test set to ensure you are getting correct results. For testing use a sliding window and slide it all over the image and score the extracted features. Take the best score, as it is most likely, that the player is located there.
6. If you want to detect several players in one image use non maximum suppression.

Note: HoG features are quite difficult to handle, as small changes in extraction might have a great impact on performance. For example openCV ships with an (undocumented) HoG detector. [HoG visualization](http://www.juergenwiki.de/old_wiki/doku.php?id=public:hog_descriptor_computation_and_visualization) helped me to understand how it works.

**EDIT: fixed HoG visualization link**

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I just want to know when you talked about generating a positive and negative training set, you mean that I have to extract the hog features from the negative and positive samples as shows the link below:   http://thebrainiac1.blogspot.com/2012/07/v-behaviorurldefaultvmlo.html

Comment: Exactly. You extract the positive HoG features at the (known) positions of the persons. The negative features are extracted at any position of the negative images (if they do not have persons on them). If you have persons on the negative data set, ensure you do not extract the features of the person, this would screw the whole thing.

Comment: The hog visualization link is broken. :(

Comment: just fixed it, for what reason ever the link has changed